# Find the distribution of Y-X

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Consider the following two experiments: the first has outcome X taking on
>   the values 0, 1, and 2 with equal probabilities; the second results in an (independent) outcome Y taking on the value 3 with probability 1/4 and 4 with
>   probability 3/4. Find the distribution of Y-X.

**Attempt:**

For this problem, I assigned a 1/3 probability to the values, 0, 1, and 2
first, I tried to find all the possible combinations P(X=0, X=1)=(1/9), P(X=0, X=2)=(1/9), P(X=1, X=2)=(1/9), P(X=0, X=3)=1/9, Then, I tried to find P(Y-X=3), but got -1/12, How should you solve for this?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

You have to build a table of sorts:
$$
\begin{array}{cc|cc|c|c}
X & Y & f_X(x) & f_Y(y) & D & f_D(d) \\
\hline
0 & 3 & 1/3 & 1/4 & -3 & ? \\
1 & 3 & 1/3 & 1/4 & -2 & ? \\
2 & 3 & 1/3 & 1/4 & -1 & ? \\
0 & 4 & 1/3 & 3/4 &  ? & ? \\
1 & 4 & 1/3 & 3/4 &  ? & ? \\
2 & 4 & 1/3 & 3/4 &  ? & ? \\
\end{array}
$$
The last 2 columns will give you the distribution you seek if you condense them adding the probabilities for the same values of $D=X-Y$. Can you finish this?